# Trying to duplicate an API tutorial on edureka

Tags: javascript, rest

Would like to find out why I am getting this error on script.js

https://www.edureka.co/blog/what-is-rest-api/

I get an error when trying to:

```
node script.js
```

```
C:\Users\aemon\WebstormProjects\vanillajs\script.js:17
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
?[90m at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:16)?[39m
?[90m at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1111:27)?[39m
?[90m at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)?[39m
?[90m at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)?[39m
?[90m at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)?[39m
?[90m at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)?[39m
?[90m at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m

C:\Users\aemon\WebstormProjects\vanillajs>
```

The error above references to:

> "The JavaScript exception "invalid assignment left-hand side" occurs when there was an unexpected assignment somewhere. For example, a single " = " sign was used instead of " == " or " === ".Apr 15, 2020"

Line 17 of script.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =&gt; {
```

If I change it to

```
app.get('/', (req, res) ==&gt; {
```

I get a different error (n/a).

Comment: Please post your stack trace here and any code that is relevant.

Comment: the script.js is a bit large to post but it is listed here in the middle of the page: https://www.edureka.co/blog/what-is-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ''= & g t ;''' is the HTML entity for ">"  so the author of this article did not parse the code correctly when she posted it on the website.